# Qt not finding include files after qmake and jom

Tags: qt, makefile, path, qt5, qmake

I am having the following problem after trying to install Qt in a new machine.

My process was following:

I am using MSVC 2019 and Qt 5.15.2, so I downloaded both like I had in my old machine. I downloaded Qt using the Maintante Tool and have all the dependencies I had in my other laptop.

After opening my project, I configured my kits for my deployment, like this:
Notice that the build directory is not in the same level as the source directory, but that is desired and has never been a problem in other machines.
(There is also a clean step, just like the Make build step with the argument "clean".
](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UC0E2.png)

After running qmake, everything looks normal.

When Trying to build, I am getting the following warning:

"Error: dependent '..\ ..\ ..\ ..\ ..\Qt\5.15.2\msvc2019_64\include\QtWidgets\QDialog' does not exist.
10:09:22: The process "C:\Qt\Tools\QtCreator\bin\jom\jom.exe" exited with code 2.
Error while building/deploying project XXXXXXX (kit: Desktop Qt 5.15.2 MSVC2019 64bit)
When executing step "Make""

I have checked that my makefile looks the same as my other machines with these relative paths to the include.

All System Environment and Qt Version Variables look also to the same. i. e. libs, includes, etc.

If I don't do a shadow build and let Qt build on the orange level, no complains, he builds, but that is not what I want (and cannot run it as a lot of dependencies are missing).

My other machine with same config looks exactly like that. No idea what is happening.
Can someone enlighthen me or know why Qt is complaining / not finding the include files where they are?

Answer (score 0):

Updating from my side.
For future people facing the same issue: I did not have any uncommon character in the paths more than underscores.

My fix:
I figured with some help and testing deploying to other folder structures that qmake was the problem and complaining.
Placing the whole project one level up (C:\Repos\NewLevel\ ...) fixed the issue and no problem from Qt whatsoever.

It is purely a workaround that Qt seems to be ok with. As my version control begins after NewLevel, it is also not an issue. Maybe I will try in the future to take it down one level after some update in Qt, but AFAIK it is not a reported bug.
As I said, other machines with identical Project Strcture using same Qt Version and QtCreator seemed to be okay with that. The Makefiles look also the same in terms of relative paths.